# Is there any university program that offers an intro statistical methods class that is bayesian -instead- of a frequentist one?

Tags: bayesian, teaching

Is there any university program that offers an introductory statistical methods class that is bayesian -instead- of a frequentist one?

Surely every intro to stats class in every program in the world, whether agronomy or economics or psychology or a service class by the stats department, is primarily frequentist based.

And just as surely there are many (but not all) programs where later in the curriculum there are some specialty courses (requiring a few stats pre-reqs) that are titled 'Intro to Bayesian Statistics'.

But **are there at least some places somewhere that offer a bayesian class as *the* intro statistical methods class?** (either as the only intro to stats -or- simply as an alternative first class to a frequentist intro)

I would count an intro stats class that teaches bayesian methods in addition to frequentist ones.

If such programs are not as rare as I imagine, then is there any indication of percentage?

I am wondering how easy it is to have a bayesian methods course without first having a frequentist methods course.

Comment: 1) any suggestions as to how to edit to make this better for this site? 2) if not, any suggestions on a better site for this? Presumably [hsm.SE] or [academia.SE] except I figure here on [stats.SE] there would be people more likely to actually know the answer.

Comment: There is a mathematics education stack: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Dave thanks! Reposted there.

Comment: Just as a comment I would like to name the book "Statistical Rethinking: A Bayesian Course with Examples in R and STAN (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science)" which builds things up in a pure Bayesian way without refering to Frequentist knowledge.

Comment: @Bernhard yeah that text would be perfect for such an intro class (though structurally/superficially it doesn't seem to 'match' a traditional intro stats class). [Will add to this migrated question over at Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18955/is-there-any-university-program-that-offers-an-introductory-statistical-methods)